# Systems of Equations word problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How would I set up equations to solve:
9 lbs. of mixed nuts containing 55% peanuts were mixed with 6 lbs. of another kind of mixed nuts that contain 40% peanuts. What percent of the new mixture is peanuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No equation in there, this is just a weighted average of two values (two percentages):

$$
New\space percentage = \frac{Sum\space of(weight\times percentage)}{Sum\space of\space weights}
$$

Applied here, it becomes:

$$
New\space percentage = \frac{9\times 55 + 6 \times 40}{9 + 6}
$$$$
New\space percentage = 49.4 \%
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  I wouldn't really do equations, just calculate.  How many pounds of peanuts are in each part?  How many total pounds of peanuts do you have?  You have $15$ pounds of total nuts, so what is the percentage of peanuts in the total mix?